# Powershell script that looking for specific word in file which created in last 1 Min

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Just wrote Powershell script that will look in Sub-Folder about the file which include ".doc_" in it's name that created 1 Min ago then to move it to another Sub-Folder.

When I ran the powershell script it will move that file which having ".doc_" in it's name that created 1 Min ago but also it will move same files which had ".doc_" in it's name that created days ago which is not required.

Could you please let me know why my code take in consideration files which is more than 1 Min

```
get-childitem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test\Test2" | where-object {$_.Name -match ".doc_" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).Adddays(-0) -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddMinutes(-1)}| move-item -destination "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, your filter for `Get-Date` is wrong in the sense of it grabbing everything *before* 1 minute ago. This is due to the `-lt` operator, which should work if you swap it with the `-gt` operator.

Okay, next subject. Since you're not actually searching for specific words inside files, but instead in the file names, we can use the [FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_filesystem_provider?view=powershell-7.2) Provider to filter for that file name, which we will sacrifice *RegEx* (*using -match*), to using *wildcard expressions*; this will speed things up  to 40x faster as sending anything down the pipeline is quite *expensive*:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test\Test2" -Filter "*.doc_*" | 
    where-object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) } | 
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test"
```

And if time is of the essence, we can try avoiding the pipeline using the the *grouping* operator `( .. )`, and the `.Where({})` operator/method.

- It's considered more of an operator due to the fact that it doesn't perform any direct action against the object(s) themselves.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test\Test2" -Filter "*.doc_*").Where{ 
    $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) 
} | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test"
```

Comment: Wow, thats so informative and professional reply thank you very much Abraham Zinala!!!